# Im trying to copy a folder from one destination to another, and it works using a batch file

Tags: batch-file

Here it is:

```
xcopy /s %systemdrive%\users\%username%\Desktop\Program\folderx  %appdata%\.home\saves
```

but that is only if I copy the folder to the desktop, is there a way where I can simply click the batch from anywhere i.e. D Drive, H Drive, My documents, on any windows machine and it copies to the .home\saves

---

Edit:
Sorry was a bit vague

Folderx is in another Folder on the desktop called "program". The batch file is also in the folder entitled " program" on the desktop. When I double click the batch file, it copies the " Folderx" and its subdirectory to %appdata%.home\saves. But lets say I have it on my flash, and someone copies it to their C drive. Is there a universal way for the batch file to still copy folderx, regardless of where the "program" folder is?

Also let me know.

Comment: so you want to copy anything from the directory where the batch file is in?

Comment: I don't quite get what you want. where is the folder located that you want to copy?

Comment: perhaps `xcopy /s .\folderx  %appdata%\.home\saves` but that takes folderx only when in the same directory as where the batchfile is.

Comment: Are you wishing to copy the folder from a location relative to the running batch file?

Comment: Unfortunately, despite your edit, the question is still vague. Where do you want to have the batch file? and folder? before copying to `%AppData%\.home\saves`? You surely aren't expacting the batch file to determine the location of a folder called `Program` on somebody elses system, _(and yes I tried, there are three on this PC matching that name)_

Comment: ok, so then what you want to try and achieve is to do a `dir /s` for each drive letter, find `folderx` and then copy it to `%AppData%\.home\saves`?

Comment: @Compo He is very vague with the question yes, but I don't think he is looking for a folder called `program`, instead he wants to search for `folderx` but until he provides solid questions, I am as lost as you are. :)

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear, but here goes. This will copy folderx if it exists in the same directory as the batchfile.

```
xcopy /S .\folderx %appdata%\.home\saves
```

This will copy ALL directories and files from the where the batch file exists.

```
xcopy /S .\* %appdata%\.home\saves
```

If you are a bit more specific with the question, I can add the options